# Is there a good way to work with a remote git repo in Windows?

Tags: windows, git

I want to be able to use Windows-based development tools (e.g. Winmerge, Eclipse, etc.) on a repo sitting on a remote Linux machine.  With my current setup, I issue git commands in a shell via VNC, and therefore use the Linux-based tools -- kdiff3, gitk, gedit, etc.  I do have access to all elements in the repo (source, .git/, etc.) via a Samba share.  With this share  -- mapped to a Windows network drive -- I work with whatever version my current git branch is pointing to.

Is there a Windows-based solution that works with a remote repo (say, over SSH) that allows me to execute the majority of my workflow (checkout, commit, diff, merge, etc.)?

Comment: Something is not clear to me: do you clone the repo on your Windows machine?

Comment: @CharlesB - No, the repo is not cloned on the Windows machine; it sits on the remote Linux machine. Cloning the repo on my Windows machine wouldn't be an option.

Comment: not cloning the repo makes no sense to me; how can you work then? can you explain the reason?

Comment: @CharlesB - The repo is indeed cloned, just not on the Windows machine.  Basically, I logged into the Linux machine in which I cloned a repo located on some remote server.  This repo is one of many that I work with; they all span multiple GB in size, so physically having all the source on the Windows machine -- with which I have a limited amount of space -- is not feasible.  The repo (i.e. my git workspace) sits on the Linux machine, but I would _like_ to use my Windows machine to see and control the repo and accompanying source.

Comment: Mmm so you have access to the working copy over a network share without cloning it on local disk. Got it :)

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/)? Its a <strike>cygwin</strike> mingw based git client for Windows. I used it while I was using Windows and it works fairly well.

Comment: Msysgit isn't cygwin, it's mingw based. It can integrate directly with `cmd` command shell. Just watch out for config parameter core.autocrlf.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I must have confused it with the bash shell that ships with msysgit; I think the shell and some of the other *nix utilities that ship with it are cygwin based.

Comment: @Chaitanya - The unix utilities are mingw / msys based. The are all Windows exes.

Comment: @Chaitanya - MSysGit can do both: you can install this as 'git bash' only or integrate it with cmd. You choose it at install.

Comment: Does git-for-windows issue remote git commands from a Windows machine to a Linux machine hosting the repo?

Comment: @Marcin Yeah, I remember that it provides both options.

Comment: @Philip Yes, if by "remote git commands" you mean whether `git push` or `git pull` works, yes it works perfectly well with msysgit.

Comment: @Marcin - what do you mean both? They are all windows exes ( in the git bash case) and exes and cmd files in the case of cmd integration. Checkout installdirectory/Git/bin and /Git/cmd.

Comment: @Chaitanya - No, I don't mean git commands that push or pull from a remote repo.  Rather, I mean "does git-for-windows issue git commands on a _remote_ Linux machine".  For example, can I tell the tool sitting on my Win machine to commit a change that's sitting on the remote Linux machine?

Comment: I don't think msysgit or any other git tool does that out of the box. You will probably have to write a script to ssh into the remote machine and execute the commands there.

Comment: @manojlds: at install you can choose whether you will use git via bash shell (separated from system; most common way) or directly from `cmd` shell (adds to PATH). For the second way there is a warning on possible complications (can override native find/sort).

Answer (score 1):

[GitExtensions](https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) is a Windows GUI around msysgit, mentioned by Chaitanya. It has drawbacks but allows most Git operations to work in a graphical interface. I use it since I switched to Git.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`TortoiseGit`](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/downloads/list) to manage a clone of the repo right on your local machine. Your IDE should then be able to perform git operations directly on it. (Well, [`NetBeans`](http://netbeans.org/) can at least, I'm not an Eclipse user, so I'm not sure what git support it has built-in.)

Answer (score 0):

`MsysGit` and the `Git Gui` are pretty effective from Windows. [Start here](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/)

I have found that they do all the basics pretty well, and then I swap over to a `git bash` window [a git/unix version of a DOS cmd window, though more powerful] for the more specialist commands.

It has worked quite effectively and doesn't need any great expertise.